# Why do my NPC's fall through the world when I select them as triggers?

Tags: unity, collision-detection, collider, meshcollider

I'm making a game in Unity where when the player comes into contact with an NPC it will switch scenes. I have the code for it and made sure all NPC's have rigidbody as well as using gravity and convex. They do not fall through the world but as soon as I click the trigger box on the mesh collider they start falling straight through the world. The switching scenes code works fine - I tested it and it does switch the scene.

Answer (score 1):

When you set the `isTrigger` property of a `Collider`, it no longer registers collisions with incoming rigidbodies/colliders. As a result, your NPC falls through the floor.

If you want the scene transition to occur immediately upon contact with the NPC, you could simply uncheck `isTrigger` and put your scene transition code inside of `OnCollisionEnter()` instead of `OnTriggerEnter()`.

Comment: Done that thanks makes sense but now it wont transition at all. My code for it is. Void OnCollisionEnter(Collider collider) and then a simple if statement to check the tag of the object its colliding with and if it is the right tag it will switch scenes

Comment: @DeclanWadsworth Does your player also have collider/rigidbody components?

Comment: Yes both my player and object (which is a t-rex that is supposed to move around) have rigidbody and mesh colliders @Alex Myers

Comment: Could you please post your `OnCollisionEnter()` code in a GitHub Gist or something?

Comment: Please consult [the docs for the `OnCollisionEnter` message](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html). Its argument is of type `Collision`, not `Collider` like `OnTriggerEnter` uses. Since your method signature does not match what the engine is looking for, it does not call the method when a collision occurs. Fix the signature and it will be called.